# How to change focus in GridView on key navigation QML

Tags: image, qt, gridview, qml

I'm trying to change focus of an image while pressing keys (left, right, up and down) in GridView. When I press left, right, up or down key, I should change image focus and change the image when focus on that image is true. Otherwise, if focus is not on the image, old image should be seen.

Here is what I have by now:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Component.onCompleted: {
        mojgrid.focus = true
    }

    function dobioResponseNapraviModel(response) {
        console.log("dobioResponseNapraviModel", typeof response)

        mojgrid.model=response
    }

    function request(){
        console.log("BOK")

        const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
        const method="GET";
        const url="http://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/1";
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5YjBkOGVlMGQzODdiNjdhYTY0ZjAzZDllODM5MmViMyIsInN1YiI6IjU2MjlmNDBlYzNhMzY4MWI1ZTAwMTkxMyIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.UxgW0dUhS62m41KjqEf35RWfpw4ghCbnSmSq4bsB32o');
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xhr.readyState===XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                var status=xhr.status;
                if(status===0 || (status>=200 && status<400)){
                    //the request has been completed successfully
//                    console.log(xhr.responseText.results)
                    dobioResponseNapraviModel(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).results)
               }else{
                    console.log("There has been an error with the request", status, JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText))
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }





   /* function request(url, callback) {
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("GET", url, true)

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState===4) {


                callback(xhr.responseText)


            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", url)
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5YjBkOGVlMGQzODdiNjdhYTY0ZjAzZDllODM5MmViMyIsInN1YiI6IjU2MjlmNDBlYzNhMzY4MWI1ZTAwMTkxMyIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.UxgW0dUhS62m41KjqEf35RWfpw4ghCbnSmSq4bsB32o');
        xhr.send()

    }*/




    GridView {
        id:mojgrid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 250
        cellHeight: 250
        model:request()
        currentIndex: modelData.id
        keyNavigationEnabled: true
        focus:true


        Keys.onPressed:{
                    if((event.key === Qt.Key_Left) || (event.key===Qt.Key_Right) || (event.key===Qt.Key_Up) || (event.key===Qt.Key_Down)){
                        image.source="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"+modelData.poster_path
                   }
        }

       /* Keys.onUpPressed: {
           request()
        }*/
      delegate: Rectangle{ id: rect; width: 350; height: 400; color:'gray';
          Image{id:img; width:parent.width; height:parent.height-200
                 //fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                 //source:"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400" + modelData.backdrop_path
                source:focus?"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"+modelData.poster_path : "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400" + modelData.backdrop_path

               Rectangle{
                   id:rect2
                   width:parent.width
                   height:text.height
                   anchors.top:img.bottom
                   color:'black'
                 Text{
                       id:text
                       text:modelData.title
                       font.pointSize: 11
                       //anchors.top:image.bottom
                       elide:Text.ElideNone
                       color:'white'
                   }

                }

                MouseArea{
                id:mouse
                anchors.fill:parent

                onClicked: {
                    parent.focus=true
                }
              }



          }

          Rectangle{
              id:rect3
              width:parent.width
              height:200
              anchors.top:rect.bottom
              color:'red'
              z:10

              Text{
                  text:modelData.release_date
                  anchors.left:rect.left
                  anchors.top:rect.bottom
                  color: 'white'

              }
          }





      }
    }
  }
```

I have `Keys.onPressed` here with an if condition, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified and reformat your code little bit but this code snippet is doing what do you want to do. When key navigation is enabled `GridView` is handling index update by itself. Actually key navigation is working and when you press keys current index is updated. `GridView` also handles limits on navigation, when you press down in the last row nothing happens as same as when you press left on the first column. The trick is using `currentindex` to update image.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    function dobioResponseNapraviModel(response) {
        console.log("dobioResponseNapraviModel", typeof response)

        mojgrid.model = response
    }

    GridView {
        id: mojgrid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 250
        cellHeight: 250
        model: request()


        keyNavigationEnabled: true
        focus: true

        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 350
            height: 400
            color: 'gray'

            property bool isCurrent: mojgrid.currentIndex === index

            Image {
                id: img
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height - 200

                source: isCurrent ? "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"
                                + modelData.poster_path : "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"
                                + modelData.backdrop_path

                Rectangle {
                    id: rect2
                    width: parent.width
                    height: text.height
                    anchors.top: img.bottom
                    color: 'black'
                    Text {
                        id: text
                        text: modelData.title
                        font.pointSize: 11
                        //anchors.top:image.bottom
                        elide: Text.ElideNone
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouse
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    onClicked: {
                        mojgrid.currentIndex = index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function request() {
        console.log("BOK")

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        const method = "GET"
        const url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/1"
        xhr.open(method, url, true)
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
                    "Authorization",
                    'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5YjBkOGVlMGQzODdiNjdhYTY0ZjAzZDllODM5MmViMyIsInN1YiI6IjU2MjlmNDBlYzNhMzY4MWI1ZTAwMTkxMyIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.UxgW0dUhS62m41KjqEf35RWfpw4ghCbnSmSq4bsB32o')
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                var status = xhr.status
                if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
                    dobioResponseNapraviModel(JSON.parse(
                                                  xhr.responseText).results)
                } else {
                    console.log("There has been an error with the request",
                                status, JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText))
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Muhhammet Ali Asan, thank you so much, this is very helpful:)